# Compile android app in raspberry pi

Tags: java, android, linux, raspberry-pi

i want to compile a android APP in a raspberry pi with gradle.

I have a build tools, images sdk and other data from my computer to the RPI, set the ANDROID_HOME and install gradle version..
Then when i run the compile process i get this error:

```
Running gradle assembleRelease
on builds/2014427_1738212
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jakewharton/butterknife/5.0.0/butterknife-5.0.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jakewharton/butterknife-parent/5.0.0/butterknife-parent-5.0.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/dagger/dagger/1.2.1/dagger-1.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/dagger/dagger-parent/1.2.1/dagger-parent-1.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/dagger/dagger-compiler/1.2.1/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.3.0/javawriter-2.3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jakewharton/butterknife/5.0.0/butterknife-5.0.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/dagger/dagger/1.2.1/dagger-1.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.3.0/javawriter-2.3.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/dagger/dagger-compiler/1.2.1/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.jar
:Firext:preBuild
:Firext:preReleaseBuild
:Firext:checkReleaseManifest
:Firext:preDebugBuild
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:compileLint
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:packageReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:preBuild
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:preReleaseBuild
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:checkReleaseManifest
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:compileReleaseAidl
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:compileReleaseRenderscript
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:mergeReleaseAssets
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:generateReleaseResValues
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:generateReleaseResources
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:packageReleaseResources
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:processReleaseManifest
:libraries:AndroidBootstrap:processReleaseResources FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13 mins 10.381 secs

{ [Error: Command failed: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 1: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �������!8__PAGEZERO__TEXT: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 2: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 3: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 3: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 2: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: ��__symbol_stub__TEXT: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 4: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt:�__stub_helper__TEXT$�: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 5: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: $�: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 6: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �__cstring__TEXT��: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 7: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
/home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 8: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':libraries:AndroidBootstrap:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-4.4/android.jar -M /home/pi/dev/firext/cifirext/builds/2014427_1738212/libraries/AndroidBootstrap/build/bundles/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/pi/dev/firext/cifirext/builds/2014427_1738212/libraries/AndroidBootstrap/build/bundles/release/res -A /home/pi/dev/firext/cifirext/builds/2014427_1738212/libraries/AndroidBootstrap/build/bundles/release/assets -m -J /home/pi/dev/firext/cifirext/builds/2014427_1738212/libraries/AndroidBootstrap/build/source/r/release --non-constant-id --output-text-symbols /home/pi/dev/firext/cifirext/builds/2014427_1738212/libraries/AndroidBootstrap/build/bundles/release
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 1: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �������!8__PAGEZERO__TEXT: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 2: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 3: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 3: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 2: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: ��__symbol_stub__TEXT: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 4: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt:�__stub_helper__TEXT$�: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 5: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: $�: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 6: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �__cstring__TEXT��: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 7: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: �: not found
    /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: 8: /home/pi/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

In my normal pc this compile ok..whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you copied the build tools that work on your computer, most likely an x86 architecture to the PI, which is ARM.

If I do a

```
file .../aapt
```

on my computer, I get

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386 ...
```

which will certainly not work on the ARM architecture. The strange error messages also hint in this direction. An [answer in the raspberry pi forum](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14634) states that you are out of luck.